# Print a form from another link on clicking a button

Tags: javascript, html, css, user-interface, frontend

I'm trying to figure out how to print an image from another web page link on clicking a button.
I know `window.print()` but how could I specify the other link I want to print the image from?

Answer (score 0):

### Same domain

If the page you wish to print is from the same domain as the iframe's parent then MDN has a [good example](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Printing#Print_an_external_page_without_opening_it) of how to do this.

You should create a hidden iframe, load your page in it, print the iframe contents and then remove the iframe.

JavaScript:

```
function printURL( url ) {
    var frame = document.createElement( "iframe" );
    frame.onload = printFrame;
    frame.style.display = 'none';
    frame.src = url;
    document.body.appendChild(frame);
    return false;
}
function printFrame() {
    this.contentWindow.__container__ = this;
    this.contentWindow.onbeforeunload = closeFrame;
    this.contentWindow.onafterprint = closeFrame;
    this.contentWindow.focus(); // Required for IE
    this.contentWindow.print();
}
function closeFrame () {
    document.body.removeChild(this.__container__);
}
```

HTML:

```
<button onclick="printURL('page.html');">Print external page!</button>
```

### Cross domain

If the page you wish to print is from another domain then your browser will throw a Same-Origin Policy error. This is a security feature that forbids scripts accessing some data from different domains.

To print cross domain content you will need to scrape the page's source and load it into the iframe. The browser will then believe that the iframe's content comes from your domain and won't hiccough when you try to print.

However, if you try to do this in the frontend, this just pushes the problem back one step further, as the same-origin policy also won't let you scrape content from another domain in this way. But the same-origin policy for data scraping is the equivalent of tying a bull up with cotton thread - it doesn't really hold you back - so this hurdle is easily circumvented. You can either write your own backend script (in PHP or your choice of language) that will scrape the content and deliver it to your page, or you can use any one of a number of web services that already do this. https://multiverso.me/AllOrigins/ is as good as any, it doesn't require backend programming, and it's free so I'll use that in this example.

Using Jquery, the modified `printURL` function from above would be:

```
function printURL( url ) {
    var jsonUrl = 'http://allorigins.me/get?url=' + encodeURIComponent(url) + '&callback=?';
    // the url / php function that allows content to be scraped from different origins.

    $.getJSON( jsonUrl, function( data ) {
        // get the scraped content in data.content
        var frame = document.createElement( "iframe" ),
        iframedoc = frame.contentDocument || frame.contentWindow.document;
        frame.onload = printFrame;
        frame.style.display = 'none';
        iframedoc.body.html( data.contents );
        document.body.appendChild(frame);
    }
    return false;
}
```

The other functions from above would remain the same.

Note that if the page you're printing is built using AJAX calls or is significantly styled with scripting then the iframe may print something that looks quite unlike what you were expecting.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but is there any other way to be able to print something from different domain?